# longtable contents from file

Tags: longtable, input

I observed a difference in a longtable environment that reads it contents via an "\input" command. longtable package version 4.17 creates an additional empty line, that is not present with longtable package version 4.13.
Here the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,final,pdftex]{report}
\usepackage{longtable}[=v4.13]

\begin{document}
Contents of table read from file:
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}[t]{|c|p{10cm}|c|l|}
\hline
{\bf Rev.} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\bf Änderung} & {\bf Datum} & {\bf Name} \\\hline
\endhead
{\bf Rev.} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\bf Change} & {\bf Date} & {\bf Inc. by} \\\hline
\endfoot
% --------------
\input{test_inp.tex}
% --------------
\end{longtable}
\end{center}

Contents of table inserted directly:
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}[t]{|c|p{10cm}|c|l|}
\hline
{\bf Rev.} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\bf Änderung} & {\bf Datum} & {\bf Name} \\\hline
\endhead
{\bf Rev.} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\bf Change} & {\bf Date} & {\bf Inc. by} \\\hline
\endfoot
% --- start contents of file test_inp.tex ---
A
&
B
&
C
&
D
\tabularnewline
\hline
% --- end contents of file test_inp.tex ---
\end{longtable}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

And here the file "test_inp.tex":

```
A
&
B
&
C
&
D
\tabularnewline
\hline
```

It produces the following:

[image]

If I replace the "\input{}" by the contents of the file "test_inp.tex", the table looks fine:

[image]

With the old package v4.13, both tables are fine.
For me its unclear what the difference makes and how I can avoid this additional blank line with the new package v4.17. I need to stay with the "input" command because the file is generated automatically by a complex document creation tool.

I hope, anyone can help me to fix this problem.

Regards,
Chris.

PS: tex-live of Cygwin 3.1.4 and 3.4.7

Comment: unrelated but don't put longtable in a center environment (it doesn't center it)  and beware using `\bf` it's not defined by default in latex. You haven't shown any code that produces the output shown, did it really work in 4.13, I'd be surprised, as `\input` is not expandable. You can revert to 4.13 with `\usepackage{longtable}[=v1.13]`

Comment: please fix your example so that it can be run to see the problem and test answers (the answer is probably use `\@@input test_inp.tex` but I would expect that to apply to all versions.

Comment: I updated the so that it can be run. It seems that "\input test_inp.tex" (without the {}) fix the problem - what is the difference??

Comment: It can't be run by anybody but you because only you have `test_inp.tex`.

Comment: Contents of file "test_inp.tex" added above.